# concatenate multiple MySQL fields into one JSON response

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a novice. I want to concatenate 3 fields (city, provinceName, countryName) from MySQL into comma separated strings and return the strings in JSON with "city" as the key. I can't get the strings and I can't construct them into complete text in JSON.  My PHP is:

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT city GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT city, stateProvinceName, countryName SEPARATOR ',') FROM neighborhoods
WHERE countryAbbreviation='$countryAbbreviation' AND stateProvinceName IS NOT NULL
") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
$row_array['city'] = $row['city'];
array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

When I test the query, it is not comma separated. Instead I get Quebec CityQuebecCanada. When I run the web site, the JSON response is only {"city":"Quebec City"}.  The desired response is {"city":"Quebec City, Quebec, Canada"} - or in a general case, multiple "city" objects.

What should I change. Please be specific. I don't follow general instructions well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use city field instead of concated string.

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(',', city, stateProvinceName, countryName) AS full_address FROM neighborhoods
WHERE countryAbbreviation='$countryAbbreviation' AND stateProvinceName IS NOT NULL
") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
$row_array['city'] = $row['full_address'];
array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: That's a big step forward, as I'm getting the 3 fields, but they don't have commas.  I get [{"city":"Quebec CityQuebecCanada"}]

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT shows up in pink in my MySQLWorkbench. That probably means something, but I don't know what. The test query does not concat the commas.

Comment: Try `CONCAT_WS` instead of `GROUP_CONCAT`. `GROUP_CONCAT` is used with `GROUP_BY`. I've updated answer. But maybe you want to group by those results?

Comment: Thanks, the test query works, and the web site gets the correct content in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(....)
{
     $city = $row['city'] . ", ";
}
//cuts off last comma, alternatively convert above loop to do/while
$city = substr($city, strpos(",", $city, -1));

echo json_encode($city);
```

Comment: If you do this approach, why not: while(....)
{
     $city[] = $row['city'];
}

echo json_encode(implode(',',$city));

Answer (score 0):

Use group by clause on city when you want to have distinct values for each city.